# get rid of first column when converting dtm Matrix to DataFrame

Tags: r, tm

I've converted a Document Term Matrix to a dataframe using this simple line

```
dtm.df <- as.data.frame(inspect(dtm))
```

The problem is I want to remove the first column (filenames) but the column has no name.

Comment: Did you try subsetting with `[,-1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be two different issues here: rownames vs. columns.

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Here you see a column printed without a name. These are the rownames. 
`mpg` is the first column. If we wanted to remove this column without refering to its name, we could use

```
mtcars <- mtcars[,-1]
head(mtcars)
                  cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

On the other hand, if you are talking about the rownames, which are still printed, you can remove them with the function `rownames`:

```
rownames(mtcars) <- NULL
head(mtcars)
  cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Understood coffeinjunky .  What if I need a substring from rownames into a new column BEFORE deleting rownames column? Using mtcars suppose I need a new column with the first word (Mazda, Datsun...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514648/how-do-i-name-the-row-names-column-in-r

Comment: https://www.google.se/search?q=how+to+select+substrings+r&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ubNNV9DkItPzsAHpmJfoAQ