# How to set the row index name in R? (Like DF.index.name in Pandas)

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, row, label

**How can I set the row index name in a `R` `data.frame` object?**

I tried looking on stackoverflow for the answer but I couldn't figure out how to even search for it? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=set+row+index+name+dataframe+R

This one kind of explains it but they are converting it to a matrix? 
[How do I name the "row names" column in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514648/how-do-i-name-the-row-names-column-in-r)

```
> dimnames(DF_c) = c("sample","cluster")
Error in `dimnames<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = c("sample", "cluster" : 
  invalid 'dimnames' given for data frame
```

In Python `Pandas`, I would simply do `DF_c.index.name = "samples"` but I don't know how to do it in `R`.  I noticed that when I saved it `write.table(DF_c, "output.tsv", sep="\t")` It puts my column label as the row name but I can't do something like `colnames(DF_c) = c( "samples","cluster")` since there is only 1 column?

```
# Clusters
DF_c = data.frame(last_iter$c)
rownames(DF_c) = row_labels
colnames(DF_c) = c( "cluster")
```

Bonus:
How to not include the `"` when it's writing table to output?

[image]

Comment: You cannot rename the rownames vector. It's name is already `rownames` and it's stored as an attirbute. Your bonus question is a duplicate. Do some searching.

Comment: Why does it shift the column name over the rows?  I don't know the terminology in R.

Comment: I think you are asking how Excel behaves.

Comment: I don't think so.  In Pandas, when it outputs a dataframe there is a tab at the beginning of the headers so everything lines up.  I'm asking how to make R not do this. I thought by naming the row index, the problem would be solved.

Comment: I think the fundamental confusion here is presuming that R's row names serve an analogous function/purpose as what the OP is describing in Pandas. As described in the linked question, generally in R we would not use row names and instead put this information in an actual column.

Comment: @joran thanks.  That would make sense.  Pandas and R dataframes have a lot of similar functionality and I thought the row index names would be the same.

Comment: Yeah, and also note that you can (and I usually do) suppress the row names when writing to a file by specifying `row.names = FALSE`. Generally, when R is _reading_ a delimited file if there is a header row with one fewer value than the other rows, it will presume the first column is row names.

Comment: @O.rka: the defaults is not include a delimiter to hold place for a `rownames` column (that is not a variable column). It's always seemed to me to be an incorrect design of S/R but apparently you want this to be the case, so now I'm not sure why you are asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the row names and column names correctly, you just missed a piece from your 'write.table' command to remove the quotes:

```
write.table(DF_c, "output.tsv", sep="\t", quote = FALSE)
```

The reason that your column name goes over the row name in your output table seems to be a weirdness of R, you can get around it by creating a column for your row names with a column label, then writing the table out:

```
DF_c = data.frame(last_iter$c)
colnames(DF_c) = c( "cluster")
DF_c$rownames = row_labels

write.table(DF_c, "output.tsv", sep="\t", quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: With the combination of your answer and the help of @joran I got it to work w/ `# Clusters
DF_c = data.frame(last_iter$c)
DF_c = cbind(samples = row_labels, DF_c, row.names = NULL)
colnames(DF_c) = c("samples", "cluster")`