# How can I change the label of row structure into a string?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to change the type of structure in row label (the one with red rectangle) into a string(character). Any ideas/suggestion of how can I change it?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I name the "row names" column in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514648/how-do-i-name-the-row-names-column-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `rownames()` for the data.frame. You might also find the `rownames_to_column()`, `rowid_to_column()`, and `column_to_rownames()` functions from the `{tibble}` package useful:

```r
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:26)
head(dat)
#>   x
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
#> 4 4
#> 5 5
#> 6 6

rownames(dat) <- letters
head(dat)
#>   x
#> a 1
#> b 2
#> c 3
#> d 4
#> e 5
#> f 6

tibble::rownames_to_column(dat, var = "rowname") |> 
  head()
#>   rowname x
#> 1       a 1
#> 2       b 2
#> 3       c 3
#> 4       d 4
#> 5       e 5
#> 6       f 6

tibble::rowid_to_column(dat, var = "rowid") |> 
  head()
#>   rowid x
#> 1     1 1
#> 2     2 2
#> 3     3 3
#> 4     4 4
#> 5     5 5
#> 6     6 6

dat <- data.frame(x = 1:26, rowname = letters)
head(dat)
#>   x rowname
#> 1 1       a
#> 2 2       b
#> 3 3       c
#> 4 4       d
#> 5 5       e
#> 6 6       f

tibble::column_to_rownames(dat, var = "rowname") |> 
  head()
#>   x
#> a 1
#> b 2
#> c 3
#> d 4
#> e 5
#> f 6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>